# Static versus non-static lock object in synchronized block

Tags: java, static, synchronization, locking, synchronized

Trying to visualize and understand *synchronization*.

1. What are the differences between using a ***static lock object*** (code A) and a ***non-static lock object*** (code B) for a *synchronized block*?
2. How does it differ in practical applications?
3. What are the pitfalls one would have that the other wouldn't?
4. What are the criteria to determine which one to use?

**Code A**

```
public class MyClass1 {
  private static final Object lock = new Object();
  public MyClass1() {
    //unsync
    synchronized(lock) {
      //sync
    }
    //unsync
  }
}
```

**Code B**

```
public class MyClass2 {
  private final Object lock = new Object();
  public MyClass2() {
    //unsync
    synchronized(lock) {
      //sync
    }
    //unsync
  }
}
```

**Note**

The above code shows constructors, but you could talk about how the behavior is different in a static method and a non-static method too. Also, would it be advantageous to use a static lock when the synchronized block is modifying a static member variable?

I already looked at answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774442), but it's not clear enough what the different usage scenarios are.

Comment: "Note that the above code shows constructors," That is an important distinction. A synchronized block with an instance field on a constructor is absolutely pointless, as no two threads will ever execute a constructor on the same instance.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, that instance field could contains an object that is shared among threads. For example `private final Object lock = "niceLiteralString";`.

Comment: I understand using constructors to show an example was a bad idea. My question extends to static and non-static methods as well. Also, how does sharing the static/instance field affect the locking?

Comment: "how does sharing the static/instance field affect the locking?" The lock is not on the field, but on the *object instance* that the field contains. So `synchronized (a){}; synchronized(b){}; synchronized(c){}` could all end up using the same lock. They can also throw NullPointerExceptions, if that field is null.

Comment: @Thilo [this article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t96352.html) makes the argument that String literals should be avoided for a good reason - reuse of references by JVM.

Comment: That was just an example to illustrate that even if your field is private, the object contained there may not be.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The difference is simple: if the locked-on object is in a `static` field, then all instances of `MyClass*` will *share* that lock (i.e. no two objects will be able to lock on that object at the same time).

If the field is non-static, then each instance will have its own lock, so only calls of the method *on the same object* will lock each other.

When you use a static lock object:

- thread 1 calls `o1.foo()`
- thread 2 calls `o1.foo()`, will have to wait for thread 1 to finish
- thread 3 calls `o2.foo()`, will *also* have to wait for thread 1 (and probably 2) to finish

When you use a non-static lock object:

- thread 1 calls `o1.foo()`
- thread 2 calls `o1.foo()`, will have to wait for thread 1 to finish
- thread 3 calls `o2.foo()`, it can just continue, not minding thread 1 and 2

Which one of those you'll need depends on what kind of data you try to *protect* with your synchronized block.

As a rule of thumb, you want the lock-object to have the same `static`-ness than the operated-on value. So if you manipulate non-static values *only*, you'll want a non-static lock object. If you manipulate static values *only*, you'll want a static lock object.

When you manipulate *static and non-static* values, then it'll become complicated. The *easy* way would be to just use a static lock object, but that might increase the size of the synchronized-block more than absolutely necessary and might need to more lock contention than desired. In those cases you might need a combination of static and non-static lock objects.

In your particular case you use the lock in the constructor, which will only ever be executed once per instance, so a non-static lock-object doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: I think using the constructor as an example was a bad idea. Anyway, good answer. I want to ask one more question. Is there a way of ensure that a set of methods operating on a **volatile static** member variable via one thread will be _done and over with_ before other threads access this member variable? I can make this a separate question on SO if necessary.

Comment: @ADTC: that does sound like a separate question to me. Short answer: no, you'll need synchronization. You can avoid it only if the operation of the volatile is *atomic* (for example a single `++` on an `int`**and** you don't care about the order (i.e. you don't care if you read before or after the operation).

Comment: I do care about the read, it should only happen after the operation. I think I will ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @ADTC: actually, I mis-informed you: even `x++` isn't atomic on a volatile x. Do go ahead and ask a new question for this.

Comment: if two threads are accessing same object's two diff non-static methods , it is possible or the second thread has to wait , does the lock on one object locks all non-static methods ??

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' Yes, each thread(accessing same object resources) need to wait until other thread leave lock on any same-instance-synchronized-method.