# What is the difference between Object lock and class level lock in java Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I had read from some book and then raised me a question.It was
question related to java thread concept.

Comment: Please read through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675381/what-are-class-level-object-level-explicit-and-intrinsic-locking?rq=1

Comment: Please can you give an example to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Did you even bother to google for this? Googling for "object lock vs class level lock* gives me http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/08/thread-synchronization-object-level-locking-and-class-level-locking/ as first result. you might want to have a look at that. If you then still don't understand you can edit your question so we can see *what* you don't understand.