# static synchronized and non static synchronized methods in threads difference in behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand that static synchronized lock on Class objects, and non static locks on Object instance.

However in the accepted answer for this question: [Static versus non-static lock object in synchronized block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356795/static-versus-non-static-lock-object-in-synchronized-block)

> When you use a non-static lock object:
>
> - thread 1 calls o1.foo()
> - thread 2 calls o1.foo(), will have to wait for thread 1 to finish
> - thread 3 calls o2.foo(), it can just continue, not minding thread 1    and 2

Why can Thread 3 just continue without regarding thread 1 and 2. Shouldnt Thread 3 have to wait to acquire the lock on the Object instance 'this' from either thread 1 or 2 before it can proceed ?

Comment: Can you specify your question more? Because the question you asked is answered in the link you provided - they are different Object instances, so thread 3 is locking on another lock from thread 1 and 2.

Comment: Yes my bad I thought they were the same instance hence the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can Thread 3 just continue without regarding thread 1 and 2.

Because it is locking a different object.

(Unless `o1` and `o2` happen to refer to the same object ....)

> Shouldnt Thread 3 have to wait to acquire the lock on the Object instance 'this' from either thread 1 or 2 before it can proceed ?

Nope.  The calls attempt to synchonize on (i.e. lock) `o1` and `o2` respectively.  These will become the `this` for the respective threads when the `foo()` method calls start. The `this` of the respective threads while in the calling context(s) is not relevant.