# When task is submitted to threads in a thread pool via executor service how to ensure that only 1 thread can occupy a synchronized task at a time?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, synchronized

I have following worker class -

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    private int workId;

    public Worker(int workId) {
        this.workId = workId;
    }

    private int count = 0;

    private synchronized void increment() {
        System.out.println("Work id: " + workId);
        System.out.println("Incrementing...");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        count++;
        System.out.println("Incremented");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        increment();
    }
}
```

I have following main method -

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new Worker(i));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println("All tasks submitted");
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println("All tasks completed");
```

Here `increment()` has been synchronized. So when 1 thread is occupying it another thread has to wait until that thread leaves the lock.

But when I am submitting the work using a thread pool of 2 threads, both threads seem to be using `increment()` at the same time.

So here how can I force the two threads to use the `increment()` method only one at a time?

Comment: What do you want to have at the end? Right now you have 10 `Worker` objects, with 10 *separate* counters.

Comment: I want that when 1 worker is working on a synchronized task, that worker must have an exclusive lock at the task and another worker cannot do the same task until the firsst worker completes the task and releases the lock.

Comment: You synchronize on the worker object (`this`). If you have several worker objects, then they can indeed run in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private synchronized void increment()
```

**This method locking works at the `Object` level**, so if you have two Objects, they won't block each other when calling this, as each one *would call its own* `increment()` method (there is no concurrent call on the same `Worker` instance).

---

In order to avoid different instances accessing the `increment()` method concurrently, you need synchronization at `Class` level, which is achieved when the lock is the same for all of your `Worker` instances. Some options to declare the lock:

- **Shared **`Object`****

  ```
  public class Boss extends RichDad implements EarnLotsOfMoney
  {
     private final Object masterLock;
     public Boss() 
     {
        masterLock = new Object();
     }
     public Worker createWorker(int slaveId) 
     {
        return new Worker(masterLock, slaveId);
     }
     //...
  }
  ```

  *yep silly example i know..*

  ```
  public class Worker implements Runnable 
  {
     private final Object lock;
     private int workId;

     public Worker(Object lock, int workId) 
     {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.workId = workId;
     }

     private void increment() 
     {
         synchronized(lock) /*lock holds the same reference in all instances*/
         {
             //...
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         increment();
     }
  }
  ```

**`lock`** is created only once and then is passed as a parameter when creating the `Worker` instances. This would block all `Worker` instances created **from the same** `Boss` (*in this approach the `lock` is a non-static object*).

---

- **Its own **`Class`****

  ```
  public class Worker implements Runnable 
  {
     private int workId;
     public Worker(int workId) {
        this.workId = workId;
     }

     private int count = 0;

     private void increment() 
     {
         synchronized(Worker.class) /*class level lock here*/
         {
           System.out.println("Work id: " + workId);
           System.out.println("Incrementing...");
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           count++;
           System.out.println("Incremented");
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         increment();
     }
  }
  ```

This would synchronize the threads using the shared `Worker` **class** as lock.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to create two Worker.class locks? Like we do in creating Object locks? Object lock1 = new Object(); Object lock2 = new Object();

Comment: Take a look here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18356932/2148953

Comment: The concept is extremely clear now, thank you so much

Comment: @PayelSenapati my last assumption about locked objects is not totally correct, as non-static objects could also perform a class level locking; I included an example of this, based on sharing the same instance of an object to the instance constructors. Hope it also helps!